# How to select tweets to do twitter sentiment analysis

Tags: python, nltk, sentiment-analysis, naivebayes, textblob

I am trying to perform a sentiment analysis on Donalds Trump tweets.
I already collected about 100 tweets that seems to be very possitive or negative.
Such as

> POS: Great trip to Mexico today  - wonderful leadership and high quality people! Look forward to our next meeting.
>
> NEG: Crooked Hillary Clinton is spending a fortune on ads against me. I am the one person she doesn't want to run against. Will be such fun!

I trained NB classifier using TextBlob framework. Unfortunatelly I get about 40-50% accuracy and the most informative features are:

```
>              contains(I) = True              pos : neg    =      6.1 : 1.0
>           contains(been) = True              pos : neg    =      2.8 : 1.0
>            contains(has) = True              pos : neg    =      2.8 : 1.0
>            contains(you) = True              pos : neg    =      2.8 : 1.0
>             contains(is) = True              neg : pos    =      2.6 : 1.0
>              contains(I) = False             neg : pos    =      2.3 : 1.0
>            contains(not) = True              neg : pos    =      2.2 : 1.0
>             contains(in) = True              neg : pos    =      2.0 : 1.0
>             contains(of) = True              pos : neg    =      1.7 : 1.0
>             contains(in) = False             pos : neg    =      1.7 : 1.0
```

I think that I am doing something wrong because it decides what is the polaritiy basing on simple words such as "I, am, of, in" instead of "sad, good, tax, jail, god bless, than you".

What I have done is just run the code from the docs

```
test_set, train_set = dataset[30:], dataset[:70]
cl = NaiveBayesClassifier(train_set)
print(cl.accuracy(test_set))
cl.show_informative_features(10)
```

Is it a proper approach?
Could anyone help, please?

Answer (score 0):

This [github repository](https://github.com/maxbbraun/trump2cash) contains sentiment analysis on tweets about *Donald Trump* from *Twitter Stream* I think you will find it interesting.

In case of doing sentiment analysis on texts from social networks(un-structered text with noise) I recommend you **[VADER](https://github.com/cjhutto/vaderSentiment)** sentiment analysis tool.

There are a lot of details which you have to consider during solving sentiment analysis problem, this cheat sheet will be helpful for you
**[sentiment analysis problems]**[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rjmdg.png)

Also, you can try ***deep learning approach*** for sentiment analysis which is state-of-the-art technique nowadays. 
Check this [Kaggle tutorial LSTM Sentiment Analysis | Keras](https://www.kaggle.com/ngyptr/lstm-sentiment-analysis-keras)